# Talend - Insert records to seperate tabel based on file name

Tags: talend

I am very new to talend open studio and I am using Talend 7.3.

We have customers accross multiple zone and we have seperate table per zone.
We have multiple zone specific files named based on zone. I want to write a generic job which will process files to correct table(each zone has a separate table).

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have use multiple tFileinput and multiple targets in the same code. Your design should be something as below

```
                tFileinput1     If you need any  ---- Table1
tFileList ----- tFileinput2     transformations  ---- Table2
                tfileinput3     you can apply it ---- Table3
```

Provide the proper file pattern names in each tFileinput components and it will process into required target alone.

Comment: Thank you Macaulary for your response.But with your solution,if new zone get added or removed extsting then JOB have to update, I need generic solution.

Comment: When a new zone is added you have to create a new table in the database and add that target in the talend code. Generic solution based on the data to create the database table and loading the data is not  the right way